# How can I pass arguments to the functions called by "jQuery then"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

full code here:
     http://jsfiddle.net/BurFz/
     http://jsbin.com/dagequha/1/edit?js,console

```
/**
 *   Running this will work
 */
func1('arg1').then(func2).then(func3).then(function () {
    console.log('all done!');
});


/**
 *   But this one doesn't work
 */
func1('arg1').then(func2('arg1')).then(func3('arg1', 'arg2')).then(function () {
  console.log('all done!');
});
```

I have a 3 async functions in my code and I'm using jQuery deferred/promise technique to call them sequentially. It's working all right but the problem is that I can't pass these functions arguments.
If you run my JS Bin(JSfiddle) sample you see it works, scroll down and use the second commented section(the one with arguments) instead of first one and it will stop working correctly. How can I pass arguments to func1, func2 and func3 and still call them sequentially?

Comment: Your code belongs within your question.

Comment: sorry @KevinB I don't exactly understand what you mean, do you have any problem opening the link I shared?

Comment: @Quentin this is definitely a brand new question and the problem is about using "jQuery then" function not passing arguments generally.

Comment: @ImanMohamadi No, the problem with your code only being in jsbin is if we or anyone who visits this page can't get to jsbin, your question becomes useless to that person. It also may affect search results.

Comment: Also, *"not passing arguments generally"* yes, that is exactly what this question is asking and the solution in the linked question does show how to solve your problem.

Comment: Take it easy @KevinB, the question you linked for was totally targeting something different and made me confuse. Even the answers are the same it's always good to add some details for the questioner just like Michael did for me.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that this is a duplicate of the linked question. The fact that you're using .then and they're using something else is irrelevant.

Comment: If I knew the source of my problem, I wouldn't come to stackoverflow in the first place. end of the story, this question is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it would work

```
$.when(func1('arg1')).then(function(){
    func2('arg1');}).then(function(){
        func3('arg1','arg2');}).then(function () {
             console.log('all done!');
});
```